# Why does Excel need me to double click on each cell for it to sum properly?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I opened a CSV file and Excel displays a green tip on the top-left hand corner of each cell where there is a number. When I try to compute a subtotal of a column, it gives me the wrong value.

Setting Format as "Number" or "Currency" doesn't do anything as the sum is still incorrect. When I hover over the green tip, it doesn't display anything. The only solution that works is manually double clicking each cell, then clicking off that cell. I have to do this for every cell which is very time consuming.

I'm using Excel on a Mac, would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Those are Numbers stored as Text.

When clicking on the green tip you should see a ***Convert to Number*** option which will also fix it. When selecting a range of such cells (with the last selected one having had such a green tip) you should be able to click the tip and convert the whole range to numbers.

If that doesn't work for you, the [official way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885) to bulk convert them to proper numbers is as follows:

1. Select the whole column that has this issue (you can select one or more cells instead. Just be sure the cells you select are in the same column, otherwise this process won't work)
2. Go to the Data tab and click the **Text to Columns** button (the Text to Columns button is typically used for splitting a column, but it can also be used to convert a single column of text to numbers
3. Click **Finish** (the rest of the Text to Columns wizard steps are needed for splitting a column. Since you're just converting text in a column, you can click Finish right away, and Excel will convert the cells)